# How to secure connection between multiple microservices PHP

Tags: php, laravel, microservices, api-gateway

I will develop a microservices architecture with laravel in PHP, but i don't find any informations about how to secure the connection between the gateway and microservices.

For example, i will have 2 microservices :

1. User
2. Trade

With that, i will have a api gateway who will check the jwt of user with access ... and forward the request to right service.

It is the right way to do it ?
And how to secure to prevent the user to directly request the microservice ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Api with oAuth can be a good fit for your use case.
You can have an api for each micro service and put oAuth in front of it to authenticate who has access to what.
oAuth provide different type of Grants if you want to authenticate services or users you should chose the right grant suited for you.
oAuth also provide scopes so you can have some users/services with more access thant others etc.
In Laravel there is [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) that leverage all the oAuth stuff for you

Please check the doc above about Grants and Scope